# dynamically load an image as a prop in react

Tags: reactjs, image, dynamic, material-ui, react-props

I am trying to load images dynamically in react and pass them as props. I have a data.json file that is basically an array of article objects.

```js
title:"article1"
headline:"headline1"
image:"/src/images/articleimage1"
articleContent:"ipsum lorem"
```

in the first component I map through the array and return a "card" with props

```js
    const featuredArticles = imageCardArray.map(elem => <ImageCard 
        title={elem.title}
        headline = {elem.headline} 
        image= {elem.image}
        
        />)
   

    return (
        <div className ="center">
{featuredArticles}
        </div>
```

then I use those props in the card component itself. It all works perfectly except for the images

```js
function ImageCard(props) {
  return (
    <div className="imageCard">
      <Card>
        <CardActionArea>
          <CardMedia
            component="img"
            image={props.image}
            title={props.title}
          />
          <CardContent>
            <Typography gutterBottom variant="h5" component="h2">
              {props.title}
            </Typography>
            <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary" component="p">
              {props.headline}
            </Typography>
          </CardContent>
        </CardActionArea>
        <CardActions>
          <Button size="small" varient="outlined">
            Artigo completo
          </Button>
        </CardActions>
      </Card>
    </div>
  );
}

export default ImageCard;
```

any ideas how to load these images? the card component is from material UI if it helps. (it says in the docs that the image property just accepts a string)

I can get the image to load in the card by importing it at the top and then image = {image}, but of course then it is not dynamic and all the cards have the same image. please help!! thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to import the image from directory at top

`import ArticleImg1 from 'image path';`

and then construct your array of objects like this

```
{
  title:"article1"
  headline:"headline1"
  image:ArticleImg1
  articleContent:"ipsum lorem"
}
```

If I understand your question correctly it will work.

Comment: I think it would work but its not really very dynamic. as I would need to always open the code and import the image into lots of components everytime add a new article. instead of just adding the image into a folder and then reading the path from a single json file serving many components. as the image would also be used in the main article page for example. basically to update the entire site I would only like to add the image to images folder and update the json file with its path

Comment: just as a note, it works perfectly if you put an ""h t t p://stolen-online-image"" as the value in the JSON file

Comment: You can create a javascript file with all the images import  in the same file and can export that with your data as an array of object or object depending upon your requirement. So in every component you just need to import the data you want to use. You don't need to import image in every file.

Answer (score 0):

the answer is here https://medium.com/react-courses/5-top-methods-to-import-and-load-images-dynamically-on-cra-react-local-production-build-855d3ba3e704

you need to have in your json just the file name for the image, not the full path.

```
title:"article1"
headline:"headline1"
image:"articleimage1"
articleContent:"ipsum lorem
```

then in the card component:
you can either assign the resource to a component ...

```
const Image = require( '/src/images/'+ props.image);
```

and in the JSX

```
<img className="card-img-top" src={ Image } alt="image not found" />
```

or do the require in the jsx

```
 <img className="card-img-top" src={ require( '/src/images/'+ props.image) } alt="image not found" />
```

assumption made that all images will be in the same folder...